# serial communication and change value of Variable on Slave RAM C

Tags: c++, c, communication

I want through serial communication change value of Variable on Slave RAM

for example

```
snedtoslave(byte address, data)
```

but here i don't know how make variable with fixed address on ram in slave

i want this

```
//in slave
char x=0; // address in ram  example 0b
serialreceiver(); 
if(x==1) {do();}

//in master
snedtoslave(0b, 1);
```

how can i make variable with fixed address ?

Comment: Which platform? And [tag:c] of [tag:c++]? Pick one.

Comment: You need to use some protocol (Modbus for example) on top of serial communication.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution, using [c](/questions/tagged/c), without involving linker, is to use a table that holds all information:

- Logical address of variable
- real address of variable
- type of variable

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef enum
{
    INT8, UINT8, INT16, UINT16, INT32, UINT32
}my_TYPES;

struct table
{
    uint32_t address;
    my_TYPES type;
    void     *variable;
};

uint32_t Var_1 = 10;
uint8_t  Var_2 = 20;

struct table variables[] = {
//    address |  type  | variable
    {   0     , UINT32 , (void *)&Var_1 },
    {   1     , UINT8  , (void *)&Var_2 }
};

int main(void)
{

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(variables) / sizeof(variables[0]); i++)
    {
        switch (variables[i].type)
        {
            case UINT8:
                printf("Old value of variable at address %d: %d\n", variables[i].address, *((uint8_t *) (variables[i].variable)));
                *((uint8_t *) (variables[i].variable)) += 1;
                printf("New value of variable at address %d: %d\n", variables[i].address, *((uint8_t *) (variables[i].variable)));
                break;
            case UINT32:
                printf("Old value of variable at address %d: %d\n", variables[i].address, *((uint32_t *) (variables[i].variable)));
                *((uint32_t *) (variables[i].variable)) += 1;
                printf("New value of variable at address %d: %d\n", variables[i].address, *((uint32_t *) (variables[i].variable)));
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Type not managed\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```